# How to read an array list from csv file using python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a csv file with ";" separator where information are look like,

```
Id;arrVal
0;[[84, 109, 423, 466]]
1;[[242, 192, 822, 594], [242, 640, 818, 911]]
2;[[123, 212, 401, 351]]
```

I am reading the csv file and want to get the array for specific Id by using following code

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/csv/file.csv", sep=";")
df[df['Id']==1].iloc[0]['arrVal']
```

It gives me the value `[[242, 192, 822, 594], [242, 640, 818, 911]]` but as a string. How can I extract as a 2D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
x = ast.literal_eval(df[df['Id']==1].iloc[0]['arrVal'])
```

Answer (score 3):

That column is also valid JSON syntax, so you could use:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',sep=';')
L = json.loads(df[df['Id']==1].iloc[0]['arrVal'])
```